# JSON data type for relational DATABASE

Tags: json, nosql, relational-database, sqldatatypes

Can a relational database have JSON as a data-type?  Or Does relational data need to have such a data type.
I know it makes more sense to store such data in NoSQL like MongoDB or Redis. But suppose if have a small data to be stored as JSON and use it quickly within a relational database context.

Example : I want to store some configurations . In future those configuration's name:value pair might keep on increasing and i dont want to keep adding columns. I can store in text format with some separator or just like to use JSON and put it in as string in DB. ( thats why i was wondering if relational DB can itself have JSON type and I don't have to bother about parsing and storing) .

Some could also argue that my data-model is not 100% correct and thats why i am having such requirement , which can be true as well. But still i feel relational DB could have JSON type.

What's your thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PostgreSQL` now has a `jsonb` data type where you can store and query json.

Query json examples: http://schinckel.net/2014/05/25/querying-json-in-postgres/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do the thing which is explained in your example than **XML store** is better for you.

but if data is increasing day-by-day than **nosql have performance issue** if you have no proper platform for SQL databases.

so you need to go for **Nosql** for your requirement **Document Store or Ket-Value Pair databases** is better for you.